# .net core 3 host: how to detect console mode

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I made a simple ASP.net core web API project, using the generic host:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
```

Now, I'd like to be able to detect if the app was launched as a command-line application ( `dotnet myapp.dll` ) or if it is being hosted by something else (like IIS, for example).

In the former case, I would like to be able to provide some interactivity to the console, like here:

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        if (IsConsoleApplication)
        {
            await host.StartAsync();
            while (true)
            {
                string s = Console.ReadLine();

                if (s == "q")
                {
                    await host.StopAsync();
                    return;
                }

                //Run command according to the value of s
                // ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

I already attempted to implement IsConsoleApplication with

```
    Environment.UserInteractive;
```

or

```
    Console.In != StreamReader.Null;
```

but I had no success.

Is there a good way of doing such test?

Comment: Why in gods name? Generic host already provides a means for graceful shutdown when you do Ctrl+C (or send a SIGTERM and the like)

Comment: how about try `Console.ReadLine` ？

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

IIS or IIS Express will set environment variables like IIS_DRIVE, IIS_USER_HOME, ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH, etc.
So you can possibly check their presence via

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("....")`

You would need to test all your environments though, to make sure the variable is reliable enough.

**Option 2**

Consider an option to start the "interactive" mode via a command-line parameter, eg.

```
dotnet myapp.dll interactive
```

In the code, check if the value of `args[0]` is "interactive".